# Desk.com and JIRA Integration

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am very new to JIRA. Here is my requirement. I am involved in Desk.com Integration with JIRA Cloud.
Desk.com:
There is app called as Custom Action: Following are the parameter

1) URL: I need to pass the value to JIRA using this parameter (Ex: https://myjira.atlassian.net)

2) Data: JSON Data with the Values.

I Could not figure out this part:

I hope I should write some webservice method in JIRA(The URL should point the URL specified in Desk.com) and the method should accept the JSON Data.

Once the method is called successfully from Desk.com, I can able to create/update JIRA issue.

Please help with better solution.

I am also confused with JIRA Cloud and JIRA Servers also. But the version I am using is JIRA Cloud.

Thanks guys,
Vijay

Comment: So you are trying to send data to Jira to create/update issues, correct ? You can send REST calls from your application to Jira REST API. Check here https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

Answer (score 0):

So you need to create Rest Service as part of Jira Plugin?

[This is possible](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/atlassian-platform-common-components/rest-api-development/rest-plugin-module) as part of [Jira Plugins2](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-architecture/building-jira-add-ons/jira-plugins2-overview).

But unfortunately Jira Cloud [doesn't support custom Jira Plugin2 addons](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/Cloud/Atlassian+Cloud+and+Add-ons). 
And [Atlassian Connect](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/guides/introduction.html) that supports Jira Cloud doesn't have possibility to create Rest Service as part of the addon.

So you need to change you requirements or do not support Jira Cloud or have this service as another app that would be connect with Jira throw [REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/).